# Breaking on External Call

Tags: node.js, express

I'm able to `break` on requests in NodeJS. However, when I try to set a breakpoint in a callback function (which makes an external request), it fails to break.

Is there some option I need to set to make this work? Or, is there another approach that I need to take?

```
app.use('/feed', function(req, res, next){

    instagram.set('client_id', 'id'); /* can break here */
    instagram.set('client_secret', 'secret'); /* and can break here */

    instagram.tags.info({
      name: 'tagone,tagtwo',
      complete: function(data){
            console.log(data); /* trying to break here ... */
        }
    });
});
```

FWIW, I'm using [`node-inspector`](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) and [`instagram-node-lib`](https://github.com/mckelvey/instagram-node-lib).

Comment: What do you mean by break?

Comment: have code execution stop at that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need no extra Tool. The
Complete callback is never executed if your debugger does not stop there. To prove it, write something static like

```
console.log('invisible')
```

to the console in the callback and execute without debugger. It should not print anything to the console

Comment: my friend, you are indeed correct! i should've stepped into the 3rd party code. chalking this one up to how green i am to debugging nodejs apps, thanks for the guidance!